# Не обновляются миграции в Django

Tags: django, миграция

Имеется запись в базе данных, при попытке добавить новую - ничего не происходит. Я новичок, прошу отнестись с пониманием.

```
class Women(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
content = models.TextField(blank=True)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d/")
time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
cat = models.ForeignKey("Category" , on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post', kwargs={'post_id': self.pk})
```

class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

При исполнении такого кода, я ожидаю, что уже существующая таблица Women_Women обновится, что и происходит, а так же создам новую, Women_Category, но этого не происходит

Comment: `при попытке добавить новую - ничего не происходит.` - как добавляете и как знаете, что ничего  не происходит? `При исполнении такого кода` - сам по себе этот код ничего не делает, только определяет модели в коде. Вы пишете про добавление записи в БД в одном месте, и "не обновляются миграции" в другом. В чем же все таки проблема в добавлении записи или что-то не так (что?) с миграциями?

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, и извиняюсь за то, что неверное подаю информацию, я сам не во всем разобрался.  Я написал данный код в models.py  , чтобы в файле db.sqlite обновилась инфомрация. В классе Women я добавлял информацию в ранее созданную таблицу в этой строчке - cat = models.ForeignKey("Category" , on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True) . а класс Category я пытался создать. В итоге Women - обновился, а Category не был создан

Comment: Когда вносите изменения в модели (в питон код), нужно создать миграцию командой `python manage.py makemigrations`, а потом применить ее к базе данных, командой `python manage.py migrate`. Таким образом изменения в моделях будут применены к БД (если, скажем добавили новую модель или поле, то они будут добавлены в ту БД, которая у вас указана в настройках джанго)

Comment: Я все именно так и делаю, но новая таблица "Categories" не появляется

Comment: Ну во-первых, это нужно в тексте вопроса написать, как догадаться сделали вы это или нет. Далее, при выполнении этих команд никаких ошибок нет? Еще вы не ответили, как вы проверяете, что таблица Category не была создана? Файл с миграцией, в котором создается таблица был создан после makemigrations?

Comment: Если я правильно понял про проверку, то я просто запускаю sql studio, и не наблюдаю там таблицы Categories, но таблица Women успешно обновляется. При выполнении команд ошибок нет. Файл с миграцией это файл с расширением .db? Он был создан, при создании первой таблицы. За неправильно составленный вопрос извиняюсь. Это мой второй вопрос на этой платформе, первый был удален)

Comment: Файл с миграцией, это файл *.py в каталоге migrations. `таблица Women успешно обновляется` что именно вы имеете ввиду? Извиняться за вопрос не нужно, каждый когда-то начинал, нужно улучшить вопрос, а именно недостающую информацию добавить в вопрос кнопкой "править". Не нужно в комментариях отвечать. И еще добавьте в вопрос вывод команды `python manage.py showmigrations` - у меня стойкое ощущение, что миграции не запускались или не прошли успешно.